# requirejs error on page navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

I've had this happen in Chrome and IE...

If I click a link to navigate away from a page while requirejs is still loading or getting scripts, I get random errors.  Sorry if this is vague...

For example, in require.js itself, I received an error today:

```
Unable to get value of the property 'normalize': object is null or undefined
```

In the following block:

```
//If current map is not normalized, wait for that
                //normalized name to load instead of continuing.
                if (this.map.unnormalized) {
                    //Normalize the ID if the plugin allows it.
                    if (plugin.normalize) {
                        name = plugin.normalize(name, function (name) {
                            return normalize(name, parentName, true);
                        }) || '';
                    }

                    //prefix and name should already be normalized, no need
                    //for applying map config again either.
                    normalizedMap = makeModuleMap(map.prefix + '!' + name,
```

I've received other errors in my own defined js files where they start executing the code before the dependencies are fully loaded.  I get the feeling that when the browser is asked to navigate away from the current page, it stops all ajax calls and thus truncating some of the js.

Is there a way to prevent these sort of errors?

Answer (score 0):

Avoid running code in the `define` function's scope. Start your app's logic once everything has loaded by writing your code in functions that get executed when your page is ready.

Also what do you mean by *navigate*? If you navigate away the page goes away, as well as its errors. Is this pushAPI style navigation with the app staying loaded, or a complete and full browser navigation?

Comment: Navigate as in click a standard link on the page.
Not sure what you mean by avoid running code in the define functions's scope.

Comment: As an example, say I've got a script file called exampleScript.  It's contents may look like the following.  If I click a link on the page before everything's loaded, I'm getting an error saying ko is undefined, or maybe moment is undefined...

`define('exampleScript',
    ['ko', 'jquery', 'lodash', 'moment'],
    function(ko, $, _, moment) {
        var observableLocalTime = ko.observable(moment());
  $('body').append(observableLocalTime);
});`

Comment: I've never seen errors like this, but if the user is navigating away how does it become visible to them or you?

Comment: What I mean by defining code in function is don't write code that executes immediately when the file is loaded. Define functions, then call functions when everything you need is ready.

Comment: When I click on a link, the browser hits the js error immediately.  If I have the devtool bar open, it highlights the error there before making the transition to the linked page.

Comment: I think I follow your suggestion not to run code in the define function's scope...  So my example above where I'm trying to set the observableLocalTime, I should be setting that in an init function maybe instead of inline like it's written?

I guess I'd understood that require would not execute any of the code until it had all dependencies scripts loaded, so this would be safe.

Comment: I don't think this is really anything you have to worry about. It sounds like the error is in require.js itself and it happens as people leave. Very few people are probably debugging your app in that way and if they are just tell them to stop.